# How to check that DartType of Element is custom type?

Tags: dart, dart-analyzer

`DartType` from analyzer package have some properties:
`isDartCoreNum`, `isDartCoreInt`, `isDartCoreDouble`

How to do check DartType is custom type (`DartType` represents `Employee` or `Bus` NOT `int` or `double`)?

This is necessary for I need to discover `FieldElement` type during analyze of code. How to do it?

Answer (score 0):

You can use `TypeChecker` from `source_gen`.
ie:

```dart
TypeChecker.fromRuntime(Employee).isAssignableFromType(myType);
```